# I need help testing NServiceBus.Send(command).Register(delegate) in a MVC 4 Web API service call

Tags: testing, moq, nservicebus

I'm implementing a call to NServiceBus.Send() inside a MVC 4 Web API Service call.  I'm doing this in .Net 4, so I don't have access to C# 5 features (async, etc.).

I'm very new to Moq, so I'd appreciate some advice creating the correct way to Setup Moq for this.   I did look at [Mocking a delegate wrapper using Moq][1] and [Testing Bus Send in an application using NServiceBus][2] but my understanding of Moq is still to primitive to adapt for my testing needs, especially with the Tasks involved to deal with the asynchronous calls:

```
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(Command command)
    {
        var commandCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        var commandCompletionTask = commandCompletion.Task;

        Bus.Send(command).Register<CommandResult>(status =>
                            {
                                var response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode(status) };
                                commandCompletion.SetResult(response);
                            });

        return commandCompletionTask;
    }
```

I run into trouble because I don't know how to reference the commandCompletionTask within  the mockedBus...   My failed attempt looks like this:

```
 _commandController = new CommandController(MockBus.Object);
  MockBus.Setup(b => b.Send(It.IsAny<ICommand>()).Register<CommandResult>((Action<CommandResult> s) => 
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode(s) };
                commandCompletion.SetResult(response);
            }));
```

Writing this allowed my brain to come up with a couple of ideas...

1. To Moq TaskCompletionSource, but that doesn't have an interface, so can't be Moq'd apparently.
2. To use a real TaskCompletionTask, (which allows me to test for the Task returned from CommandController.Post()).  Sadly this didn't work any better, as I get an error from LINQ as it tries to process the delegate.

Ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Would it be possible to shim something in between and have a sync version of Post for testing purposes?

Comment: I could, but part of the point is to Mock IBus so that it acts like the real IBus when interacting with the API Call and then I can test to see that the API call does what it does.    One of the problems here is that there is no good persistent storage as far as I can tell with MVC WebAPI.  There's an example on NServiceBus' page that shows a test for IBus.Send() within MVC that uses ViewBag to hold request state.   There's no similar thing in MVC WebAPI.